# While flipping breakers on and off, I had my hand shocked

Tags: electrical

Going through breakers on my panel my hand got shocked.  Went to the off position and felt hot current go thru my hand.  Nothing too bad, but made me jump.  My panel is unlabeled, so I'm not sure what the breaker is wired to.  Was flipping breakers to see what what was being powered.  Should I be concerned?

Comment: Doesn't matter.  The breaker didn't shock you, the **panel** did.  The *whole* panel is electrified.  In fact, *your entire Equipment Grounding Conductor network may be electrified, your oven's chassis, your switchplate cover screws, you name it.*  That's a tough & scary one that is probably revealing a serious problem with your house's Grounding Electrode System.  **This can kill you at any time.  Being lucky a few times does not make you immune to electricity, *every* touch is Russian Roulette**.   The source of the current could be from any breaker.

Comment: I just answered a very, very, very [similar question here](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/145622/120-volts-on-the-metal-for-the-breaker-box/145659#145659).

Comment: Oh, to clear up [correlation/causality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_does_not_imply_causation): You had a problem in mind when you operated that breaker.  *No connection*.  You stumbled upon this new, unrelated problem, and it's much more serious, and needs solving now. That other problem goes on the back burner.

Comment: Where are you on this planet, and do you have a non-contact voltage detector pen (volt-alert, chicken-stick)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, absolutely. Call an electrician and make sure nobody touches the board. There might be 2 problems: operating circuit breakers must never result in getting an electric shock. That could be  caused by one or two  metal parts near the switch with different potential. Or the switch and board is very dirty inside and outside, which caused a surface current to the hand. This is the first issue to be corrected. Probably there is a second problem, i.e. a missing RCD = residual current device which is upstream of a circuit breaker and interrupts when current is flowing through the body.  But a RCD does only interrupt if a ground current is involved. If the hand was touching a phase and neutral and the rest of the body was well insulated from ground ( dry weather, insulating soles, dry skin, dry clothes, etc.), a RCD does not prevent a shock.